# Meter Main as Subpanel

Tags: grounding, bonding

I have a meter socket box on a pole with a couple of circuits going to outside. I want to run some feeder wires to a service equipment box on a workshop structure thru underground conduit. Since the meter main is also considered a Subpanel and there is a ground electrode there, I am unsure of where the out the ground electrode and where to bond. Located in Central Florida

Comment: Usually every detached building needs it's own grounding rods/system.  Your question is not clear, so maybe you can edit it to be better.  Neutral bus bars are only bonded to ground bus at the main panel, usually the panel that is fed by the meter first.

Comment: Please clarify whether this is (roughly): "Meter in meter main at the main building, ordinary subpanel to be installed in workshop" or "I have a meter main (with no meter) that I want to reuse as a subpanel".

Answer (score 2):

The meter main is *not* considered a subpanel. It is considered the *main* panel, hence the name. The basic setup is:

- Hot/Hot/Neutral into meter main from utility. (Hots go to the meter, neutral bypasses the meter as the neutral current does not need to metered - it is always the difference between the hots.)
- Neutral is bonded to ground in the meter main. This is the only place neutral should be connected to ground.
- A ground wire going to an Ufer ground or 1 or 2 ground rods is connected to the meter main. This protects the building that the meter main is attached to.
- One or more breakers are used to feed power to large loads and/or subpanels. Configurations vary a lot, depending on the number of breaker spaces in the meter main (a quick search shows anywhere from 2 to 42).

All circuits (whether a subpanel feed or an individual device) fed from the meter main will have at least one hot, a second hot or neutral or both (for a subpanel you would definitely have both) and a ground wire.

Any subpanel in another building needs to have its own ground rod(s) (1 or 2 or Ufer) connected to the panel. Neutral and ground are not bonded in the subpanel. Most subpanels come without neutral and ground bonded, but sometimes you will use a "main" panel as a subpanel out of convenience and/or cost, and then the neutral ground bond needs to be removed (usually just one screw).

Comment: Interesting. So in my post-upgrade system, which has a meter main on the outside wall in addition to the (now main-breaker-less) box inside, the bonding would have been done at the former? Good to know.

Comment: @keshlam Correct. And it is quite common to end up with a meter main outside and then inside have a "subpanel" that is a full "main panel" in every way except grounding - i.e., it will have a main breaker (since that's the way big panels come in packages), lots of spaces, etc. with just two things different from the old standard: neutral ground bond removed and no ground wire to ground rods (because that instead goes to the meter main).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Tnx.

Comment: @keshlam are you the same person as OP? Coz you may be confusing us by talking about a different setup.

Comment: Nope, I'm someone else; I was just checking my own understanding of what had been said. Apologies for the digression.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking in terms of the equipment that is on the barn, that is formerly a meter-main and you now want to feed it from the meter on the pole... look at the labeling on it.

### Suitable only for use as service equipment

That labeling will be your downfall.

North American standards require that *at the first disconnect switch past the meter* (which is almost always a circuit breaker), the neutral from utility supply must be bonded to the ground from the ground rods. Thus you have 4 things coming together: utility neutral, ground rod, house neutrals and house grounds.  As such, house neutrals and grounds are allowed on the same bar, which does not need to be insulated from the panel enclosure.

Subpanels need isolation between neutral and ground.

Most panels/load centers capable of taking a main breaker, are configurable either way. The neutral bar is insulated, there's a bonding strap or screw that can be removed, and they sell accessory ground bars for like $6. Easy peasy.  This equipment is labeled **"Suitable for use as service equipment"** since it can swing that way. (unlike, say, a 6-space panel with no possible location for a main breaker).

However, meter-mains are not like that. Because the meter is present, **they assume** the equipment will be Service Equipment and they don't necessarily provide a means to insulate neutral from ground. Because they don't provide that, they label it "**Suitable ONLY for use as service equipment**".

NEC 110.3(B) requires we follow the panel instructions and labeling, so *that is that*.

Now if you wanted to cheat it, and you had only a limited number of circuits to deal with, you could simply *not use the neutral bar for neutrals*, have the neutral wires bypass the normal attachment points, and use some alternate neutral-splicing method which physically and electrically floats - such as a Polaris connector or ILSCO Mac Block Connector.  Then the former neutral bar becomes simply a ground bar, and there is no neutral bar - you are simply splicing it.

Comment: I think this is the right answer...to the wrong question. If OP had said "I have an extra meter main, can I wire it up to my workshop and feed it from my house", this would be 100% the right answer. But I think OP is conflating "anything that doesn't by itself feed absolutely everything" (i.e., a single main panel for the entire complex) with "subpanel". My understanding (and my answer) is based on using the already installed meter main to feed to a workshop, in addition to continuing to feed to the existing main building.

Comment: @manassehkatz I was taken to understand there was a meter out on a pole with a few breakers there (i.e. ranch panel) and OP wanted to feed a decommissioned meter+"service equipment" on the structure.

Comment: I figured that's what you thought. I don't think that's the case. But I've been wrong before.

Comment: @manassehkatz and so have I :) I'm sure OP will fill us in.